# Housepolant identification and care

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

Can anyone help me identify this house plant?

Some of the leaves have gone yellow, I think due to under watering and this seems to be improving now. Should these be trimmed?

Any other care tips appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Houseplant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a Parlour Palm, *Chamaedorea elegans*. I don't like the look of the blackened parts, that might indicate over rather than underwatering at some point, but you can cut out damaged fronds at the base, where they arise from.

I think you should move it away from the window - it's not clear whether it gets any sun, but they don't like direct sunlight, especially not during summer, so if its been getting sun, that would explain its discoloured appearance. They will tolerate quite low light conditions, but may grow more slowly, so medium to bright daylight is ideal, though some early morning or late evening sunlight will do no harm.

In regard to water, the soil in the pot should feel dry to the touch, but not so dry its shrunken from the sides of the pot - when you water, give it plenty, then empty the outer pot after 30 minutes, and again if there's any more collected 30 minutes later. Keep away from heat sources - brown tips to leaves can indicate hot or dry air. They prefer to be a bit crowded at the root, so only repot when essential. Further info here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/parlor-palm/parlor-palm-houseplants.htm

Comment: Thank you for this insightful and helpful answer :)